# CakePHP: how to register the session?

Tags: php, session, cakephp

In PHP5, the code: `session_register("");`

my code:

```
function login() {
        // Don't show the error message if no data has been submitted.  
        $this->set('error', false);

        // Production mode. No output. For AJAX
        Configure::write('debug', 0);

        // Does not render the view
        // Others method : $this->render(false, false);
        $this->autoRender = false;

        // The most important : set : debug = 0 and register session
        session_register("");

            $this->Session->write('test',"test1");

                echo $this->Session->read('test');
        }
        return ;
    }
```

Comment: don't you have an unwanted `}` before the `return;` statement?

Comment: Which version of CakePHP are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is outdated since 2001-2002

To store the data in the session you should use:

```
$this->Session->write('name', 'value');
```

To get the data stored in the session use:

```
$data = $this->Session->read('name');
```

Where `name` is the session variable name

Comment: But when I put this code ($this->autoRender = false;) in the function,the Session will can't be write.

Comment: `autoRender` has nothing to do with sessions, as well as it has nothing to do with obsolete function `session_register`, which is pointless nowadays.

Comment: when I add the code ( session_register(""); ),it will be work,and it also get the error,but the session could be write.

Comment: @Mr.Shamrocker: you're doing something wrong. The only method you need to use is `write`. Try to google any cakephp guides for newbies.

Comment: I know the code (session_register("");) does not meet the cakephp grammar,but without this ,it will be not work.

Comment: It will work if you do it properly. Are you asking for help or telling us how to do it?

Comment: Perhaps what is unclear is that `$this->Session->read()` is valid code in the controller *and* the view, whereas `$this->Session->write()` is not?